# MySQL Query Help, Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql

I have an application that has had a single table where all my data for this query was stored:

SELECT item, name, address, city, state, zip, latitude, longitude, expiration, photo, (((acos(sin((".$submission->latitude."*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos((".$submission->latitude."*pi()/180)) * cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$submission->longitude."- `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) as distance FROM `Offers`  HAVING distance < 150 AND expiration > '$daytime - 6' ORDER BY distance;

Basically the query finds the selected information, performs a calculation to find the distance from $submission->latitude/longitude and sorts by those distances.

Due to some outsourced development work, the select data is now spread out amongst 3 tables:
table business:
business_id, name, address, city, state, zip

table location:
business_id, location_id, latitude, longitude

table offers:
business_id, item, expiration, photo

I am having a heck of time getting a query to produce the same results on the split table structure.  I have tried JOIN on business_id variations, but seem to get complaints about unknown columns and/or every derived table must have its own alias.

I am by no means a good MySQL query builder, hence I am asking for some pushes in the right direction on how I might approach this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One more thing, the problem seems to be centered around the distance calculations and getting those to happen in the right place.  I am able to do a JOIN no problems on the tables, just cant add the distance calculation.  Its almost like I need to do a JOIN, then select from the joined result, just not sure how to do that.

Comment: Normally HAVING goes into queries that have a GROUP BY clause to refer to result of group calculations. I would not be surprised if you had errors from just that HAVING clause. Try using a WHERE instead and see if that resolves your problem. On another note, I don't see any JOINs in your query. Please write your query with joins and also it would be helpful if you could post the schema of the tables you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to simply join your queries

```
$t1 = business table
$t2 = location tabe
$t3 = offers table

SELECT $t1.*,
       $t2.location_id,($t2.latitude .. compute ),($t2.longitude ... compute),
       $t3.item, $t3.expiration, $t3.photo
FROM $t1
JOIN $t2 on $t1.business_id = $t2.business_id
JOIN $t3 on $t3.business_id = $t1.business_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code should do it.

```
Select b.name, b.address, b.city, b.state, b.zip, c.location_id,     c.latitude, c.longitude, d.item, d.expiration, d.photo
FROM business b LEFT JOIN location c
ON b.business_id = c.business_id
LEFT JOIN offers d
ON b.business_id = d,business_id;
```